# Parsing svg in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have SVG and html file, which has couple of java script tags and I need to find all the script tags and insert a comment before the first script tag and than after the last script tag. I am trying to achieve it using Beautifulsoup. It worked well for HTML version but for SVG it is throwing error.

```
 //for html version of file, working as expected
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data,selfClosingTags=['link','meta'])
 for num,tag in enumerate(soup.findAll('script')):
        if num==0:
            soup.head.insert(-1,startcomment)
        tag.extract()
        soup.head.insert(len(-1,tag)
        if num==len(soup.findAll('script'))-1:
            soup.head.insert(-1,endcomment)
```

but now when I try to achieve same for the svg as `soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"xml")` in the first line itself it throws exception.. svg is also xml? so I should be able to do it sameway

Update - SVG format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../../../some.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg id="mycontent" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" focusable="true" onload="Jsfunction.load()">
<script xlink:href="../first.js" />
<script xlink:href="../second.js" />
<script xlink:href="../third.js" />
</svg>
```

should be changed to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../../../some.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg id="mycontent" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" focusable="true" onload="Jsfunction.load()">
<!-- some comment -->
<script xlink:href="../first.js" />
<script xlink:href="../second.js" />
<script xlink:href="../third.js" />
<!-- end comment -->
</svg>
```

Comment: What exception does it throw? What version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: BS Version 3.2.1, the exception is something related to str and bool values, I think it is due to svg extra parameters. I don't have office system right now, so can't give the exact, will update tomorrow. But I wanted to read this xml for all scripts tags and enter the comments before and after... all script tags will be one after another

Comment: BeautifulSoup 3 development has been discontinued years ago, you really want to use BeautifulSoup 4 instead (with `lxml` installed to handle the XML parsing here).

Comment: yes I do have lxml and can upgrade BS4 ( if it supports python 2.7.x)

Comment: It supports python 2.7, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup version 4, not 3, and install `lxml` to handle XML parsing.

Currently, (as of version 4.3.2), BeautifulSoup does ignore Processing Instructions (like the `<?xml-stylesheet?>` instruction), see [bug 1294645](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1294645). You can work around this simply by patching the tree builder:

```
from bs4.builder import LXMLTreeBuilderForXML
from bs4 import ProcessingInstruction

def handle_pi(self, target, data):
    self.soup.endData()
    self.soup.handle_data(target + ' ' + data)
    self.soup.endData(ProcessingInstruction)

LXMLTreeBuilderForXML.pi = handle_pi
```

The bug has since been marked as solved, and as of BeautifulSoup 4.4 (released July 2015) you no longer need the above work-around.

You want to store the list of `script` tags in a variable so you can access the first and last tag without looping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
start_comment = soup.new_string('some comment', Comment)
end_comment = soup.new_string('end comment', Comment)

script_tags = soup.find_all('script')
script_tags[0].insert_before(start_comment)
script_tags[-1].insert_after(end_comment)
```

For your sample SVG document, this results in:

```
>>> print soup.prettify(formatter='xml')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../../../some.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg:svg baseProfile="tiny" focusable="true" id="mycontent" onload="Jsfunction.load()" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <!--some comment-->
 <svg:script xlink:href="../first.js"/>
 <svg:script xlink:href="../second.js"/>
 <svg:script xlink:href="../third.js"/>
 <!--end comment-->
</svg:svg>
```

Comment: looks great, but while reprinting it removed my stylesheet and so many params from svg tag.. is because of prettify.. any way to print the data as it is

Comment: @DevC: ah, I missed the processing instructions. My guess is that Beautifulsoup doesn't *support* PIs, better use another library here. While BS4 does try to handle XML too, it's not its core strength.

Comment: can you suggest something, I am open for anything as long as it supports Python 2.7

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html is part of the standard library. :-) `lxml`, which you already have installed, supports the same API, with extra niceties.

Comment: @DevC: note: I guessed wrong. BeautifulSoup does support PIs but the initial parse did not include the stylesheet PI. Investigating.

Comment: @DevC: ick, the current codebase for the BeautifulSoup lxml parser ignores all PIs.. tsk tsk.

Comment: @DevC: Updated to patch BeautifulSoup to handle PIs correctly in XML documents.